# Styling of options(of native select) in css works in desktop/laptop but does not work in mobile

Tags: android, html, css

It is a simple html css code with dropdown. Dropdown Works perfectly in desktop but option styling doesn't work in mobile. I need selected option to have a gray background and bold font weight. When its closed, it should look in italics.

[image: This is how select looks in desktop(Note:styling of options)]
[image: This is the final output I want which works in desktop but not in mobile]

```
<html>
<style>
    .mydropdown{
        border:none;
        border-bottom:2px dotted black;
        display:inline;
        min-width:200px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 600;
        cursor: pointer;  
        overflow: hidden; 
        background-color: lightgray;
    }
    .mydropdown:hover , .myoption:active , .myoption:checked{
        border:2px dotted #0D6EFD;
    }
    .myoption{
        font-style: normal;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .mydropdown .myoption:checked,
    .mydropdown .myoption:hover ,
    .mydropdown .myoption:active {
        background-color: lightgray;
        font-weight: 900;
     } 
</style>
<body>
<select class="mydropdown dropdown-toggle">
<option value="selans"  class="selans" >Select</option>
<option class="myoption">A</option>
<option class="myoption">B</option>
<option class="myoption">C</option>
<option class="myoption">D</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working fine even into mobile screen.

Comment: what mobile device and what browser do you use to test this? Or do you use an emulator?

Comment: I am using android phone(one plus 5t)